# NSArray to plist to TableView

Tags: iphone, nsarray, plist, tableview

Thanks in advance. I create an array with 6 parts, each an NSString in one of my views. Each string is taken from a UITextField. I want to make a save button that saves the Array into a plist. I then want a TableView to display a table sorted by the first object in the array, the first string.

I've created a blank plist with the name I want and named the plist the same thing as the array. Frankly, I'm lost after that. I don't understand if what I'm making is a dictionary in the plist or an array, and how to do it.

Once the table is made, I think I can handle pushing new views from the selected row.

Anything would help. Thanks and stack overflow has been really helpful.

Thanks again.

Comment: the root of a .plist can be both a NSDictionary or a NSArray, it all depends on how you implemented it.

Comment: if I'm taking in data in the form of an array, is there any reason to use NSDictionary and not NSArray?

Comment: if you have a lot of arrays it's better to use NSArray that way you're not bound to create random keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really set on using files, to this to write an array to your .plist:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary setObject:theArray forKey:yourKey];
[dictionary writeToFile:@"/somepath/blah.plist" atomically:YES];
[dictionary release];
```

This will set the root of your .plist file to be a NSDictionary.
If you want it to be an NSMutableArray just change the class of the *dictionary.

Answer via: [primary source](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=182954)

Comment: if the @"somepath blah.plist" is local to the iPhone, what is the path? is it just the name of the plist?

Comment: it should be just the name seen that you create it programmatically.

Comment: See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW12  for how to get to the appropriate directories when running on the device.

Comment: You should Accept the answer if it's the right one, it will help the other users viewing this question.

Answer (score 0):

To store data it's better to use NSUserDefaults and not files because reading and writing it it's much easier.
There is a primer at: [Primer link](http://ipgames.wordpress.com/tutorials/writeread-data-using-nsuserdefaults/)

Comment: I want them to be able to enter hundreds of arrays though